# WPF ComboBox IsEditable at wpf

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I have a  wpf (and ef) ComboBox that contains two fields first Name and Last name, everything works correctly
,

but I want them to look inside the box (the same idea as IsEditable="True"),  but for some reason I can not

There is a solution with TextSearch.TextPath="FirstName",

But every choice appears only the first part which is not what I want,  I would also LastName

I add the code

```
       <ComboBox  Name="comboBox1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            SelectedValuePath="CustomerId">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                            <Binding Path="LastName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

And this

```
     BeEntities bmContex = new BeEntities();
      public aaa()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var t = bmContex.Customers.ToList();
        comboBox1.ItemsSource = t;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: `public aaa()` - epic constructor (and class) name.

Comment: class and constructor They AAA

Comment: Are you sure `LastName` is arriving successfully in your Customers list? I can't replicate your problem using the above template/binding (both properties display for me).